# Topologia optima sql servers separados 10000 km

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2016

Hola a todos y gracias adelantadas por vuestras respuestas.

Os describo la situación que se me plantea. 
Tengo 4 bbdd que debo mantener exactamente iguales entre dos servidores separados 10000km.

- El tamaño de estas en conjunto son 200 GB (Una de ellas, la mayor, de 130 gb)
- Los sql son 2016
- Tienen que estar accesibles en modo lectura/escritura todas ellas.

Que solución le daríais? Si necesitáis mas información consultármelo.

Comment: Hola José, sin duda vas a requerir de un balanceador de cargas, para que las peticiones pasen por ahí y ya sea que las peticiones repliquen en todos los servidores o en su caso, tengas 2 funcionando y dos en espejo. Sin duda, no pareciera ser una tarea sencilla y también requiere inversión para lograr esto.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que indicas, recomendaría una replicación transaccional "peer-to-peer", para atender los requerimientos de que estén exactamente iguales y de que las cuatro bases de datos estén accesibles en modo lectura/escritura.

Lo único es que se requiere que la edición de SQL Server 2016 sea Enterprise Edition, lo cual, si no las tienes actualmente licenciadas así, puede incurrir en un costo adicional.

En la documentación del producto, exactamente en [Peer-to-Peer -Transactional Replication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication), puedes encontrar mayor información sobre como configurar y usar este esquema de replicación. Incluso hay un diagrama similar a tu requerimiento en la sección de topologías.

Comment: Gracias Guillermo, la replicación ha sido mi primera opción siempre. No he querido poner mis opciones para no enfocar las respuestas.